# nimrod httpserver won't work in safari

Tags: safari, httpserver, nim-lang

I'm playing around with Nimrod a bit, and I've tried the HTTPServer module. I first thought it didn't work as when I tried to go to the web page in Safari, my standard browser, it gave an error. There error was something like this: (sorry if it isn't exactly right, it's translated from dutch)

> Safari can't open this page
>   Safari cannot open page localhost:5000, as the network connection has been lost unexpectedly

But, when I try to open the page in Chrome or Firefox, it works just fine

My Nimrod code:

```
import strutils, sockets, httpserver

var counter = 0
proc handleRequest(client: TSocket, path, query: string): bool {.procvar.} =
  inc(counter)
  client.send("Hello for the $#th time." % $counter & wwwNL)
  return false # do not stop processing

run(handleRequest, TPort(5000))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like client.send writes directly to the wire - without adding the HTTP status line or any headers. You can make it working by adding at least the status line:

```
import strutils, sockets, httpserver

var counter = 0
proc handleRequest(client: TSocket, path, query: string): bool {.procvar.} =
  inc(counter)
  client.send("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n\r\nHello for the $#th time." % $counter & wwwNL)
  return false # do not stop processing

run(handleRequest, TPort(5000))
```

Comment: This answer is correct, but if you want to avoid handling such low-level details, consider using a higher-level framework for writing web apps such as jester: 
https://github.com/dom96/jester